# Floor operation in transformation

Tags: animation

I want to rotate an object a bit every second for example. I thought of the mathematical floor operation. This operation seems to be implemented somewhat, as I can enter something like `floor(10.1234)` but I want something like this `floor(#frame)` which creates this error:

```
('unexpected EOF while parsing', ('<string>', 1, 13, 'floor(#frame)'))
```

Comment: The ‘#’ is not part of the variable ‘frame’ but simply indicates that it’s a shorthand driver. You would have more luck with ‘#floor(frame)’ - although ‘frame’ is an integer and ‘floor’ would round down to the nearest integer so it doesn’t make sense as it is... presumably you need to include some other factor such as ‘#floor(float(frame)/25)’ to jump once every 25 frames...?

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem, obviously flooring a integer isn't useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ‘#’ is not part of the variable ‘frame’ but simply indicates to Blender that what you have entered should be interpreted as a Driver. In the case of '#frame' the driver simply returns the value 'frame' - the current frame of animation.

To use the floor function you should prefix the entire expression with '#' - ie, `#floor(frame)`. In order to have the value step up by 1 on each 25th frame you could enter the expression `#floor(float(frame)/25)`. This converts the 'frame' into a floating point value (technically not required - but still good practice), divides by 25 and rounds down to an integer. ie, on frames 0-24 it will produce 0, on frames 25-49 it will produce 1, 50-74 -> 2, 75-99 -> 3, etc.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer to your question, (@Rich Sedman has covered that); it's an alternative.

For stepped, repeated actions, you might consider using a [Cycles modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/modifiers.html#cycles) with an offset on the  f-Curve.

[image]

Depending on your case, it might be less fiddly, especially if there's compund animation.

[image]